# Print multiple jpg in one pdf

Tags: powershell, pdf, printing, jpeg

I am trying to print multiple JPEG files in one PDF file using PowerShell and the  *Microsoft Print to PDF* printer.

So far, I am able to select 1 image and print it to PDF using this:

```
Get-Content "myImage.jpg" | Out-Printer -Name "Microsoft Print to PDF"
```

This also works with this cmdlet:

```
Start-Process –FilePath "myImage.jpg" –Verb Print
```

But I cannot select multiple files to print in one, even though it does work in the Explorer (select all files, right click, print).

Am I missing an obvious parameter to select multiple files to input in these cmdlets or is there another one to do what I need?

Comment: I don't think what you're asking is possible with the `Start-Process` approach. It *might* be possible doing `Get-Content 'image1.jpg', 'image2.jpg', ... | Out-Printer ...`. *If* that works at all, that is, since `Get-Content` is intended for reading text files. It'd be a lot simpler to do this with proper tools like PDFtk, ImageMagick, or at least Ghostscript.

Comment: i have used itextsharp for this years ago, but i can't get it working now. if i do `find-package *pdf*` i can see that there is a package called MergePdf that claims to merge multiple pdf files into one. while it may be less than ideal, you might first create a pdf for each jpg then use this to merge them if you're stuck on using powershell

Comment: I got it working by calling ImageMagick from the powershell script :
`magick convert *.jpg -quality 100 PDF/myFile.pdf`
It's not 100% powershell but from what I have found, it's the easiest way to solve my problem, and it seams to have a lot of great options that you can call from the commands.
Thanks for the quicks replies, is there a way to mark your comment as the solution ?

Comment: See stackoverflow.com/a/72756063/2127371 for a 'pure' PowerShell solution

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to do it directly but with an intermediate step you can get there:

```
"<html><body>
<img src=`"C:\Temp\Pic1.jpg`" width=`"800`">
<body></body>
<img src=`"C:\Temp\Pic2.jpg`" width=`"800`">
</body></html>" |
Out-File C:\Temp\webpage.html
Start-Process C:\Temp\webpage.html -verb print
```

Probably not as simple as the "ImageMagick" you are using now, but it is still possible.